# Getting a WPF control to stretch vertically

Tags: wpf, xaml

I can't get my WPF layout working. I want the ListBox to stretch vertically by anchoring to the bottom of the window. It currently just sizes to the height of the controls in the `StackPanel` (the Add and Remove buttons), and resizes to accomodate items that are added. In WinForms I would just set `ListView.Anchor` to `Top|Left|Bottom|Right` but I shouldn't live in the past. I've tried a number of things like putting it in a `DockPanel`, wrapping everything in `Canvas`, etc., but nothing seems to be affected.

[image: ViewsTestListView]

Here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="FileDropAdmin.ViewsTestListView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:shared="http://schemas.markpad.net/winfx/xaml/shared"
        Title="ViewsTestListView" Height="300" Width="416">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Things:" />
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>   

            <ListBox x:Name="Things" DisplayMemberPath="ThingName" SelectedItem="CurrentThing" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <StackPanel Margin="5 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1">
                <Button x:Name="AddThing" Content="Add" Margin="0 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <Button x:Name="RemoveThing" Content="Remove" Margin="0 5 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set your second row to Height="*" and It should take all the space of the window if it's what you need

Answer (score 0):

Add another row that takes up all the remainder space...

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions> 
        <RowDefinition Height="*" /> 
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> 
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> 
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

...then adjust the row values for the text block and list box...

```
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Things:" />  
    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
```

Comment: That seems to effectively dock it to the bottom which isn't quite what I wanted, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need following options...

You second row defintion needs to be `Height="*"`

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
         <RowDefinition Height="*" />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

and your ListBox needs `ColumnSpan="2"`

```
     <ListBox x:Name="Things"
              DisplayMemberPath="ThingName"
              SelectedItem="CurrentThing"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              Grid.Column="0"/>
```

Also you said you used DockPanel... with dockpanel its even easier. All you have to set it LastChildFill="True" and add your `ListBox` as the last child in the dockpanel.

```
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
          <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <StackPanel Margin="5 0 0 0" Grid.Column="0"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                     <TextBlock Text="Things:"/>
                     <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
               </StackPanel>
               <StackPanel Margin="5 0 0 0" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Button x:Name="AddThing" Content="Add" Margin="0 0 0 0"/>
                    <Button x:Name="RemoveThing" Content="Remove"
                            Margin="0 5 0 0"/>
               </StackPanel>
          </Grid>
          <ListBox x:Name="Things" DisplayMemberPath="ThingName"
                   SelectedItem="CurrentThing" /> 
    </DockPanel>
```